# Why does npm install local packages in my home directory?

Tags: node.js, npm

Node.js newbie here, Windows 10. I `npm install`-ed some packages (without `-g`) while inside a directory that didn't have `package.json`. npm placed the packages in `C:\Users\{MyName}\node_modules\`.

Now I'm seeing some weird behavior:

- When I'm in my project directory (has `package.json` but no `node_modules/` yet), `npm list` and `npm list -g` both show an empty list
- When I'm in a non-project directory (no `package.json`)...

  - `npm list -g` still shows an empty list
  - However, `npm list` shows everything in `C:\Users\{MyName}\node_modules\`

Question 1. What is going on here? Apparently, [npm's default global path should be `C:\Users\{MyName}\AppData\Roaming\npm\`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders). If so, why is it using `C:\Users\{MyName}\node_modules\`?

Question 2. How do I get out of this mess? Node.js has no problem importing packages from `C:\Users\{MyName}\node_modules\`, but I want npm to list them properly. How can I delete the semi-global packages, reinstall them correctly, and ensure that this doesn't happen again?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Welp, turns out I've been mistakenly `npm install`-ing packages *without* `package.json`. The first time I did this, I was in my home directory(`C:\Users\{MyName}\`). This caused npm to create `node_modules/` and `package-lock.json` in the home directory. Further (mistaken) attempts to install packages in my projects--which were still missing `package.json`--caused npm to traverse upwards, until it found the initial `node_modules/` dir, and install everything there. [Because my home directory is among the places Node.js looks for modules](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders), I didn't notice my mistake until now. :P

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why it’s doing it, but the way to avoid it is to initialize your project directory using:

```
npm init
```

or if you don’t want to answer the questions:

```
npm init -y
```

That will setup the directory with the `package.json` and `node_modules` will be put there.

Comment: Welp, I never know `npm init` existed, I thought everyone was writing `package.json` by hand. Thank you!

Comment: @user2771365, it would be more polite to direct a new user to instructions on [what to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) their question then telling them to accept your answer to increase your reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a couple of tips then...

when you install a package that you are going to use in production then add --save, e.g.
npm install --save some-package

this will automatically add the dependency to your package.json. If you are installing a package for use purely in development, e.g. chai, then use
--save-dev
and it will add it to the development dependencies.

Also, git is your friend, even if you are only messing :)

Happy noding :)

Comment: You should add this answer to your other answer.  No need for  you to have two answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution here was:

1. Go to c:\users[me]\AppData\Roaming\npm and delete the node_modules folder completely
2. Make sure I had the package.json file for the project
3. Delete the project package-lock.json file
4. Run npm init
5. Run npm install

Project then worked, not sure why the node_modules got to be in the folder above, ain't got time to find out.